# How do I pass html ids and names to a dojo javascript module as parameters?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, module, dojo

I believe I'm using dojo < 1.7

The top of my JS module uses these declarations:

dojo.provide("com.kmbs.portlet.itsform.broadcastemailRequest");
dojo.require("com.kmbs.portal.core");

I've been searching for documentation on how exactly to pass the html id and name attributes to the module from the JSP.  The JSP has a form on it and there are several input fields that would be changed dynamically (via JS) depending on user input.

Example:

I have this html:

`<input id="${ns}verifyurlflag" type="hidden" name="verifyurlflag" value="0">`

I would like to use this JS in the module (will need to convert it to module format, I know.)

```
function VerifyUrl() {
    var emailUrl = document.getElementById("${ns}emailUrl").value;
    if(emailUrl){
        // Set to True (1)
        $('#${ns}verifyurlflag').val("1");
        window.open( emailUrl, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=no,resizable=yes,height=500,width=700,top=100');
    }
}
```

Where ${ns} is JSTL for automatic namespace prefixing.

Please advise.  Thank you.

EDIT:

VerifyUrl is called like this with JS in the JSP currently:

`<button class="btn" onclick="VerifyUrl()" id="${ns}verifyUrlBtn" disabled>Verify URL</button>`

Comment: So you need a way to access dynamically created element in your function? Can you add more html code ? Also how `VerifyUrl()` is called ?

Comment: @Swati - not quite, I want a way to dynamically pass html attributes to the javascript dojo  module.  Such as passing it the input id value so I don't need to hardcode it in the module itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood your question correctly , but you can pass value of `{ns}` directly onclick of `VerifyUrl()` as a parameter.So,your button will look like below :

```
<button class="btn" onclick="VerifyUrl('${ns}')" id="${ns}verifyUrlBtn" disabled>Verify URL</button>
```

**Demo code** :

```js
//value parameter passed in function will have ${ns} value
function VerifyUrl(value) {
  var emailUrl = document.getElementById(value + "emailUrl").value;
  if (emailUrl != null) {
    // Set to True (1) 
    $('#' + value + 'verifyurlflag').val("1");
    window.open(emailUrl, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=no,resizable=yes,height=500,width=700,top=100');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="aemailUrl" type="text" name="emailUrl" value="https://www.google.com/">
<input id="averifyurlflag" type="text" name="verifyurlflag" value="0">
<!--pass in function ${ns} i.e : VerifyUrl('${ns}')-->
<button class="btn" onclick="VerifyUrl('a')" id="${ns}verifyUrlBtn">Verify URL</button>
```